# 400 Message on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am trying to refresh a specific pivot table and connection/query/worksheet in the same code. I am getting a 400 error when i run in the first time. If i try again the code runs and works. Im thinking something is wrong in Worksheets("Rejects_Dashboard) line.

```
Sub RefreshAllPivotTablesAtOnce()
Dim wb As Workbook:         Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim con As WorkbookConnection

    For Each con In wb.Connections
        If con.Name = "BPO_STATS_DB" Then con.Refresh
        Worksheets("Rejects_Dashboard").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
        .PivotCache.Refresh
Next con
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you kindly fix the indentation?

Comment: `Worksheets("Rejects_Dashboard").PivotTables("PivotTable2")` and `.PivotCache.Refresh` should be a single line unless using a with block.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

```
Sub RefreshAllPivotTablesAtOnce()
    Dim wb As Workbook:         Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim con As WorkbookConnection

    'Refresh the folderContents query
    For Each con In wb.Connections
        If con.Name = "BPO_STATS_DB" Then 
            con.Refresh
            wb.Worksheets("Rejects_Dashboard").PivotTables( _
                            "PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
             Exit For 'done at this point
        End If
    Next con
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim for fixing up my code a bit. I have a command button attached to the module...when i click it the first time i still get a 400 error. If i click it again the code runs.

Comment: Its a blank 404 message. Not sure if it helps but my connection name is bpo_stats_db. If i refresh that con.refresh it should refresh the query i hage tied to that connection right? Then the second part reject_dashboard is my sheetname and pivot2table is a separate pivot table connected to reject_dashboard. Just making sure all that is right, im pretty new to vba.

Comment: Maybe check your query is not set to refresh in the background, or your pivot table will try to update before the query is done refreshing.